# Why are Arrays reference types?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

```
int[] age=new int[5];
```

After reading many posts and blogs ,I am still not clear about the fact why arrays are reference types.I know this question is like very old and have been asked plenty times but still couldnt find direct answer.

**Known things** :Since Arrays are allocated on heap,hence they are  reference types .

**Need to know**:Whats the reason behind making(compiler) arrays as reference types?.
Suppose age[0]=5,age[1]=25 ,what is the difficulty in assigning these on stack or make reference  to heap if their type was object.why consider heap as accessing time is slow comparatively?.

Why heap ,why not on stack like for structures?.

Comment: So you want arrays to be… a value type? Copied if you pass them somewhere else? What if they’re too big for the stack?

Comment: Many misconceptions in your question; start here: [The Stack is an implementation detail - part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/).

Comment: In fact, you can allocate array in stack: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/stackalloc

Comment: Maybe there is more to value types and reference types than stacks and heaps. Just a guess.

Comment: @AlexAtNet That article about allocating arrays on the stack kinda blows my mind... some fundamental feature completely escaping my awareness. I tend to avoid unsafe contexts, though.

Comment: I have read eric lipperts blog but still there is no precise explanation. One of the comment here states what if the size is huge but stack memory allocation is compile time check.  Correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: @Hameed: Why shouldn't they be reference types? As far as I can tell the reason you are suggesting is because you think they would be faster if they weren't. If that were a compelling reason (and I've no idea if they would be faster) then couldn't we use the same logic for all reference types?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but I suspect its because questions like this tend to have no useful answer. I would be reasonably sure the reason is because the spec says so. Why the spec says so is something only the writers of the spec can answer - for anybody else it would be speculation. And while you may get somebody like Eric Lippert come along who could be authoritative the chances are that you won't. And even if you do I'm not sure how helpful that is to most programmers to know the answer to this...

Comment: I thought the comments on the question were informative enough to answer the question.  It seems rather intuitive that copying a huge array onto the stack is a bad idea.  And the OP hasn't made a good argument for why they should be value types.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I am able to connect the dots.

Answer (score 4):

Several reasons:

1. value types are passed by value (as in copied). So if you called a method with a value-type array, you'd be copying all the contents.
2. Stack memory is limited and primarily designed for quick access to parameters that are in current use (as implied by the term stack). Putting a large object onto the stack would cause lookups of other local state to take much longer, because they wouldn't all be on the same cache line in the CPU cache anymore.
3. Array contents are modifiable. So you'd have all the issues that you have with mutable structs when you tried to set a value, only to find that the copy, not the "original" was modified.

EDIT:
Yes you can use stackalloc in unsafe code. Doesn't make it a good idea.